# Add timestamp to src in iframe using javascript (prevent cache)

Tags: javascript, caching, iframe, timestamp

I want to prevent my iframe from being cached. The first page isn't a problem. Then I use PHP like this:

```
<iframe id="my_iframe" src="index.html#<?php echo time() ?>"></iframe>
```

The problem I have is to prevent chaching when link is clicked inside the iframe. eg.:

```
<a href="newpage.html">this page will be cached</a>
```

How can I prevent cache of the "newpage.html"? Can I somehow add timestamp to the src using java script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes you can do that,

```
var linksList = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

for( var i=0,len=linksList.length;i<len;i++ )
    linksList [i].href += '#'+new Date();
```

this script should be placed before the closing of the body tag, or it should be generally be called after the DOM has loaded.

Now, isn't there a backend way (with headers) to ask the browser not to cache some specific pages?

Answer (score 1):

Use this code in the page header whose data you don't want to cache.

```
<?php
header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
?>
```